# Running Keystone.js app over https on Heroku

Tags: node.js, ssl, heroku, https, keystonejs

I have a web app built on Keystone.js CMS for node.js that I will be deploying with a custom domain on Heroku.  I want the whole app to run on https by default and not allow any http connections.  I've look around quite a bit and can't seem to find a definitive answer as to the best way to go about this.  Typically, i.e. for a Rails app, I would just buy a Heroku add-on SSL certificate for my custom domain(s) and point my DNS to point to the Heroku provisioned SSL endpoint.  In my app, I would configure to default all connections to HTTPS.

For a node instance (and specifically a Keystone.js instance), I'm a little unclear.  Can I just go about the same process as above, buy an SSL add-on and point my DNS to the Heroku SSL endpoint?  Do I need to do anything in the base node code to support? And how to enforce https and not allow http?

New to node and keystone and so any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

Use [express-sslify](https://github.com/florianheinemann/express-sslify).

I put it in my `routes/index.js` since the function I export from there receives a reference to the express application.

All you need to do is to tell express to use sslify, but you probably want to not enable it for development.

Since july, [Heroku defaults NODE_ENV to production](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/688) so you can do

```
// Setup Route Bindings
exports = module.exports = function(app) {

    if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
        var enforce = require('express-sslify');
        app.use(enforce.HTTPS({ trustProtoHeader: true }));
    }

    // Declare your views
};
```

That will send a 301 to anyone trying to access your app over plain HTTP.